# Are contraception effectiveness percentages per-user or per-use?

Tags: sex, effectiveness, contraception

The efficacy of contraception methods is typically given as two percentages: *typical use*, and *perfect use*.

For both of these, is the denominator of the percentage the number of **couples** who used the contraception method, or the number of **instances of sexual intercourse** during which it was used?

In other words, if a contraceptive is 98% effective, does that mean:

- 2% of couples who used this method (**any number of times**) got pregnant, or
- Of all the **individual instances** of sexual intercourse during which this method was used, 2% of them resulted in pregnancy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither.

The percentages given are the percentage of couples using that method who will conceive **over a year**. So if 100 people use that 98% method, 2 will get pregnant each year.

[Here](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/contraception/how-effective-contraception/#) is a page from the National Health Service in the UK that explains this as well as providing some numbers for some methods.